# Enumerating picture library images from folders created by non-administrators fails

Tags: 2010, web-part, picture-library

We've created a slide show webpart in sharepoint 2010. Site authors can choose a folder (or subfolder) from any picture library located on the root site. The webpart will enumerate and display images from that folder.

Now, in our production environment, it turns out that only folders in picture libraries created by our administrator user works. Folders created by authors with less rights don't. Authors are still able to choose theese folders, but if you choose one created by non-administrators, the webpart code will not enumerate any of the pictures inside them.

Audience targeting is turned off and versioning is set to 'no versioning' on our test picture library. Any tips to why this happens are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense if the development has not been considering the "Least-priviledged" user, which practically means that developer has tested it with his Administrator power at all times.

This would translate into Security permissions missing at some level (e.g. do content authors have permissions on the Top-Level site to read content?) or if you also use it for content upload.

C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Marius. Do you have any fix for this problem without changing the code and redeploying it?

Comment: Try re-inforcing Inherit Inheritance on the Library at the top-level site (if i got its location right) where you store the pictures targetted by the Web Part (under Permissions - if you don't see the button on the ribbong with "Stop inheriting permissions" - it means inheritance is broken). VALIDATE THAT YOU ARE BREAKING ANYHTING ELSE that could depend on those PERMISSIONS BEFOREHAND!!!
Then make sure your users have at least Visitor permissions on the library/site (add them to Groups rather then setting invidivual permissions).